# How to return a custom response with CherryPy

Tags: python, cherrypy

How do I return a custom response with CherryPy?

I'd like to control the status code and body.

For example in Flask I can do this:

```py
return Response(response=message, status=200, mimetype="application/json")
```

Comment: It's possible via `cherrypy.response`. For json you can also apply `@cherrypy.tools.json_out()` decorator to your request handler and return a dict.

Comment: Is there docs for this, I couldn't find any on manipulating the response

Comment: https://github.com/GDG-Ukraine/gdg.org.ua/blob/9a910e74d2ea73e96b3feec02d8412c95e67dbe4/src/GDGUkraine/errors.py#L44-L46 https://github.com/GDG-Ukraine/gdg.org.ua/blob/f682470f3d027ec41b6aeee9750c999dc535afec/src/GDGUkraine/rest_controller.py#L452-L459

Comment: `cherrypy.response` is a `ThreadLocalProxy` instance of [`cherrypy._cprequest.Response`](http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/pkg/cherrypy.html?highlight=response#cherrypy._cprequest.Response)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of returning a custom json encoded data packet

```
result={
    'some': "random",
    'data': []
}
return datastore.json.dumps(result)
```

Here is an example of returning a generated PDF (changing headers)

```
cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'
cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline;filename="report.pdf"'
return pdfblob
```

You could also check out this:
http://www.programcreek.com/python/example/2969/cherrypy.response